# CAL I - Quotient Rule to find Derivative

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this problem $h(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^3+1}$.

I get to here: $\frac{x^3+1-x^{1/2}(3x^2)}{2x^{1/2}(x^3+1)^2}$.

I started going this route:  $\frac{x^3+1-3x^{5/2}}{2x^{1/2}(x^3+1)^2}$.

The book's solution is getting this in their step process: $\frac{x^3+1-6x^3}{2x^{1/2}(x^3+1)^2}$.

How are they getting the $-6x^3$ in the numerator?

Comment: I don't even know what the question is. You have a function $h(x)$. Then what?

Comment: @mixedmath Apologize for the vague question. I'm asked to use the quotient rule to find the derivative of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}
$$ we have 
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^3+1}\right)'=\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^3+1)-\sqrt{x}(3x^2)}{(x^3+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\frac{(x^3+1)-2x\:(3x^2)}{(x^3+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\frac{-5x^3+1}{(x^3+1)^2}
$$ as desired.
Hoping it's clear for you now.

Comment: In your second step in the numerator -√x(3x^2). I got that, but in the next step, how does it work out to -2x(3x^2) in the numerator? How did you get that? I missing something in my algebra there. How does √x turn into 2x? That is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @milkIt Observe that $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^3+1)-\sqrt{x}(3x^2)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\left[(x^3+1)-2 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{x} (3x^2)\right]=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\left[(x^3+1)-2 x (3x^2)\right] $$

Comment: I'm still not seeing how are you are getting 2√x√x?

Comment: @milkIt Maybe like this it is clearer $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^3+1)-\sqrt{x}(3x^2)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^3+1)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}(3x^2)$$ and then factorize.

Comment: now I see it. I should of saw it before. Thank you for making it clear.